# How to disable accuracy check in BMC Synthetic Transaction Monitoring 10.5

Tags: synthetic

I need to disable the Accuracy check only on every execution plan configured.
The others check (Performance, Availability Errors, Execution Errors) must be active.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming. It appears to be about 3rd party application support instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide: https://community.microfocus.com/borland/tm_art/w/knowledge_base/22848/classifying-tm-art-workbench-script-runtime-error-as-availability-or-accuracy-error-in-tm-art-central

Steps:

- open file .ltz with Silk Performer
- Settings -> Active Profile -> Replay -> Simulation -> Errors tab
- Click the Add... button.
- Select a module and a severity and the list of predefined error codes will appear in the table.

For example, select "BMC TM ART - HTTP" as module and "error" as Severity. In the list of error codes, you will find the code "500" and its error description "internal server error". Below is a screenshot of some error codes for the WinSock module.

- Select the new severity
- Save and reload file .ltz

Comment: Your link is dead. Please see if there is a version available at https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/pnaOptimize/BMC+Synthetic+Transaction+Monitoring which is the new location as far as I can tell.